# Xerces C++: how do I read data from a stream as it arrives?

Tags: c++, xerces, xerces-c

I need to read data from my own stream and parse it using Xerces/C++ (SAX or SAX2) as it arrives. I've seen [Xerces Java FAQ](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/faq-write.html#faq-11) on this, but Java and C++ APIs don't really seem to match; at least, I can't see a DefaultReaderFactory class in C++ API. So, is non-buffered reading from a stream supported in C++ API? If yes, I would be grateful for a code example or an advice on how to port the Java approach to C++.

Comment: You might want to check/update your xerces-c++ library version because `XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader` should be implemented.

Comment: @Drax Thanks, you're right - it is actually just one unimplemented overload. I've simply removed this sentence from the description, beacuse the main question remains - how to port the Java example to C++ API. I believe it has been answered below though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [`SAXParser::parseFirst(InputSource, token)`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAXParser.html#3fdd21ef6c90e527b176bfc74c813516) and `parseNext(token)`, either [MemBufInputSource](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classMemBufInputSource.html) if you have the data laying in memory somewhere and can point to it, or by implementing your own [InputSource](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classInputSource.html).

Comment: Thank you; looks like a solution. And sorry, I got distracted to some other task right now, will update my comment as soon as I get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-sax2-2.html

Basically you can create an instance of [SAX2XMLReader](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAX2XMLReader.html) then you can use one of its 3 `parse` member functions to parse from the stream source you are using. Using [MemBufInputSource](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classMemBufInputSource.html) is probably the way that suits most situations.